# What is this element ID?

Tags: piece-information, part-identification

[image]

What is this element ID?? Could you please help?

Answer (score 5):

This is :

Part # 4285b
[Dish 6 x 6 Inverted (Radar) Webbed - Type 2 (underside attachment positions at 90 degrees)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4285b#T=C)

[image]